# Spring Hadoop (Hive)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hive, spring-batch, spring-data-hadoop

Am I supposed to understand how to implement **Spring Hadoop / Hive** by reading this quick guide?  I don't know where the xml configurations should go (maybe hive.xml)?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.5.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#springandhadoop-hive

Can we have more technical details on how we can proceed with a real implementation using maybe spring boot?  The only support I found is a project using release 2.2.0 of Spring Hadoop and it's already outdated.

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 1):

I have a Boot based batch-hive2 example from 2015 SpringOne conference - https://github.com/trisberg/springone-2015

With hiveserver2 you really don't need more than the JDBC driver so you  don't need much from the Spring Hadoop project. There is some batch support that can be useful if you use Spring Batch.

Comment: That's a lot of good materials, thank you very much!  Could you have developed something similar, only by looking at the Spring documentation, if the SpringOne conference had not provided such good examples.

Comment: I would agree that the docs are a bit sparse and they were mostly written before Spring Boot even existed. We are working with limited resources and I don't think we will have time to improve them until the next major rewrite of our Hadoop support targeted for Apache Hadoop 3.0.